# Search by store view only

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

I have a Magento store with `2 store views` on `1 website`. I want the default search function to just show items in that `1 store` view thats been selected. How can i do this please?

Comment: also i have changed the name attribute to search by "store only" and this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin->catalog->attributes->Manage attributes` and check **[Scope]** attributes settings `name`, `custom attribute` etc... set it from `Global` to `Store`.

**Exemple:** if you search through product name, check Scope of "name", if `GLobal` change it to `Store`.

Reindex all and clear your cache.

Comment: already done and that doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: it should work, if you search by name set the `name atribute` scope to `store view` save and reindex all and dont forget to clear your magento and browser cache.

Comment: nope unfortunately it doesnt work at all